# Cloudinary secure_url to form

Tags: jquery, html, forms, cloudinary

I am having some problems with defining a secure_url from cloudinary.

I managed to set up a working cloudinary widget to upload images. Everything works fine, i also see the secure_url printing the result in console log.

I would like to store the value from secure_log to a hidden input field. Anyone of you knows, how can i store this in input field?

Thank you in advance

Below is a code i used:

```
        <a href="#" id="upload_widget_opener">Upload multiple images</a>

        <script src="https://widget.cloudinary.com/global/all.js"> </script> 

        <script type="text/javascript">  
          document.getElementById("upload_widget_opener").addEventListener("click", function() {
            cloudinary.openUploadWidget({ cloud_name: 'company_name', sources: [ 'local', 'url', 'camera', ], upload_preset: 'my-preset'}, 
              function(error, result) { console.log(error, result) });
          }, false);
        </script>

 <input name="secure_url" id='secure_url'  maxlength="20" size="20" type="hidden" >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things to change in your code:

1. In your callback function provided to the Widget, you'd want to check for the specific event, in this case, "success" that would denote a successful upload.
2. Then upon a successful upload get a reference to the hidden input field and change the value.

For example,

```
function(error, result) {
    if (!error && result && result.event === "success") {
        document.getElementById("secure_url").value = result.info.secure_url; 
    }
}
```

Here is a working JSFiddle with the above callback function. Just set your cloud_name and upload_preset. https://jsfiddle.net/9407axhy/

**Edit:**

Based on the source code you're loading I can see that you're using the version 1 of the Upload Widget. This version has been deprecated and support will be withdrawn for it, so I suggest implementing the current Widget version. The example code I shared implements the latest Widget version.
You can find the complete documentation for the current version here: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick solution. Everything works perfectly.